# Getting the result of an Activity inside a Service

Tags: android, service, android-intent, android-activity

How can i get a result of an activity in a Service which has started that actvity?

For example: Service S -> starts --> Activity A. Now i want to send for example a boolean result back to the Service. Is that possible?

Regards,

Robert

Answer (score 2):

Call `startService()` again, packaging the boolean result as an `Intent` extra, that the service will pick up in `onStartCommand()`.

Note that having a service start an activity is unusual and may not be desired by the user, particularly if they are in the middle of doing something else.